# How can echo 1 div differently from mysql data?

Tags: php

I have some sort of timeline on my page, and I am getting 3 late news from database like that:

```
<div id="timeline">
<?php
 $SQLGetNews = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3");
 while ($getInfo = $SQLGetNews -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $name = $getInfo['name'];
    /*It should be like that
      <div class="left">'.$name.'</div>
      <div class="right">'.$name.'</div>
      I know that i have to echo it somehow by targeting first, second, third output?
    */
 }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what is your problem? Do you have some error? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to print info like left then right then left aligned, You can do this like below.

```
<div id="timeline">
<?php
 $SQLGetNews = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3");
 $i=1;
 while ($getInfo = $SQLGetNews -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $name = $getInfo['name'];
    if($i%2)
    {
        echo '<div class="right">'.$name.'</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<div class="left">'.$name.'</div>';
    }
    $i++;
    /*It should be like that
      <div class="left">'.$name.'</div>
      <div class="right">'.$name.'</div>
      I know that i have to echo it somehow by targeting first, second, third output?
    */
 }
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should illustrate something you could do to alternate between left and right while iterating.

```
function isEven(int $num):bool{
    return $num % 2 == 0;
}

$len = count($names = ['foo','bar','fez']);

$i = 0;
while($i < $len){
    $name = $names[$i];
    $class = "right";
    if(isEven($i)){
        $class = "left";
    }
    echo $name . " is on the " . $class . "\n";
    $i++;
}

// foo is on the left
// bar is on the right
// fez is on the left
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="timeline">
<?php
 $SQLGetNews = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3");
 $i=1;
 while ($getInfo = $SQLGetNews -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $name = $getInfo['name'];
    if($i%2)
    {
      ?>
        <div class="right"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
      <?php
    }
    else
    {
      ?>
         <div class="left"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
      <?php
    }
    $i++;
    /*It should be like that
      <div class="left">'.$name.'</div>
      <div class="right">'.$name.'</div>
      I know that i have to echo it somehow by targeting first, second, third output?
    */
 }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you just steal piyush's answer?